# Regex Adding a URL path except the current one I'm at

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to add something along the lines of this regex logic.

For Input:

- `reading/`
- `reading/123`
- `reading/456`
- `reading/789`

I want the regex to match only

- `reading/123`
- `reading/456`
- `reading/789`

Excluding `reading/`.

I've tried `reading\/*` but that doesn't work because it includes `reading/`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Try `reading\/\d+`

Comment: reading\/\d+ doesn't work in Hugo. Anyone have any insight, that would be helpful.

Comment: BTW `reading\/*` doesn't work because the `*` isn't a wildcard as in shell languages where it means "anything goes there", instead it's a quantifier which modifies *the previous token*, in this case the `/`, and tells the regex engine it might occur 0 or more times (which it does in every url).

Answer (score 0):

You must escape your backslashes in Hugo, `\\/\\d+`.